# Installing djiki

Tags: python, django, wiki

I'm having problems installing djiki. I followed the instructions from http://djiki.info/wiki/Getting_started, but now I'm getting a 404 error when I'm trying to open a wiki page in my browser.

The detailed steps were:

I created a new project with:

```
django-admin.py startproject mywiki
```

in /mywiki/mywiki/settings.py I added 'djiki' and 'sorl.thumbnail' to the INSTALLED_APPS, so it looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djiki',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
)
```

I also added the DJIKI_IMAGES_PATH (I had to do this at this point, because the manage.py syncdb command creates an error otherwise), which looks like this:

```
DJIKI_IMAGES_PATH = '/wiki_images/'
```

(I also created the folder /mywiki/wiki_images)

I then added (r'wiki/', include('djiki.urls')) to /mywiki/mywiki/urls.py, so the statement looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mywiki.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'wiki/', include('djiki.urls')),
)
```

Then I started the server with:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

If I open the wiki (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/`) in my browser I get the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/
Using the URLconf defined in mywiki.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)$ [name='djiki-page-view']
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)/edit/$ [name='djiki-page-edit']
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)/history/$ [name='djiki-page-history']
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)/history/(?P<revision_pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='djiki-page-revision']
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)/diff/$ [name='djiki-page-diff']
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)/undo/(?P<revision_pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='djiki-page-undo']
wiki/ ^(?P<title>[^/]+)/revert/(?P<revision_pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='djiki-page-revert']
wiki/ ^image/$ [name='djiki-image-new']
wiki/ ^image/(?P<name>[^/]+)$ [name='djiki-image-view']
wiki/ ^image/(?P<name>[^/]+)/edit/$ [name='djiki-image-edit']
wiki/ ^image/(?P<name>[^/]+)/history/$ [name='djiki-image-history']
The current URL, wiki/, didn't match any of these.
```

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 0):

Your wiki start empty and by default there is no startup page.

Visit:

http://:8000/wiki/MainPage

And djiki will let you create a page named MainPage.

Alternatively you could do this in your Url.py:

from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
...

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^wiki/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/wiki/MainPage'), name='index'),
url(r'wiki/', include('djiki.urls')),
```

...